# Implementing Php and css on certain pages in my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and website development; however, I wanted to make a plugin where I could have a table where custom tabs could be seen under certain circumstances. However, I don't understand how this specific `.css` and `.php` file with my HTML would be called in the WordPress page. In other words, how can I get my table and those files to be called on specific pages of my website?

Comment: Are you talking about sql tables or html tables?

Comment: You can do it via shortcodes defined in your plugin.

Comment: html tables @LincolnLemos